# How to inherit the same implementation of an override function in all of my activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

I am trying to implement an override method in all of the activities in my application. This override method originates from the app.Activity class. Rather than overriding this method and implementing the same exact code in every single activity one by one, is there a way to abstract this method out and apply it to every activity through inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when you create an activity, it inherits from one of the system provided Activity classes. That's what's meant by the "extends" keyword in the class declaration. By doing that, you get to use all the stuff in the system activity class as-is and get to override the methods that you want to customize. But that doesn't change anything in the base class; only your new activity class (and its descendants) will have those changes.

If you want to have the same override in all of your activity classes, you'll first want to create a minimal intermediate activity class that extends the system activity class and only overrides the method(s) that you want to customize. Then use that new class as the parent for all of your full activity classes. Each of those will then automatically use the overridden method(s).

That said, what are you trying to override? If you're just trying to change something appearance related, there are existing ways to accomplish that using themes/styles.

Answer (score 0):

The basic of inheritance is that an inherited class can keep or overwrite the methods of the parent class. In your example it would be as simple as

```
class MasterActivity extends Activity {
    public onStart() { // example
        super.onStart();
        // do something 
    }
}

class SomeActivity extends MasterActivity {
    // does the same in onStart
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a class with the method you want to override. Then inherit that class (that is going to be your parent class) in every class you need to have that method. Without writing it again you would be able to access to the method of the parent class.

```
class AClass(){
      fun methodToOverride(){}
}

class BClass(): AClass(){
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        methodToOverride()
      }
}
```